# How can I implement / use maxBy in RxJava2?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

How can I implement / use maxBy in RxJava2? I'm thinking about collect/reduce but don't know what to pass as a seed value (it should be the 1st element emitted by Observable, I could use some default value but it doesn't look clean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both the no-seed and seeded `reduce` for this:

```
Comparator<T> comparator = ... // define a relationship between Ts

source.reduce((last, current) -> 
    comparator.compare(last, current) >= 0 ? last : current);
```

For example, find the longest string:

```
Observable.fromArray("a", "bb", "ccc", "d", "eee", "ffff")
.reduce((last, current) -> 
    Integer.compare(last.length(), current.length()) >= 0 
    ? last : current)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you are on Java 8+, the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface offers some functional tools you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

A *.reduce()* operator without seed is available as well -
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#reduce-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-